# implicits for objects in Scala

Tags: scala, object, implicit

I'm confused by this description in "5.1.3 Implicit resolution" in Joshua Suareth's book Scala in depth, on Page 100:

> Scala objects can't have companion objects for implicits. Because of
>   this, implicits associated with the object's type, that are desired on
>   the implicit scope of that object's type, must be provided from an
>   outer scope. Here's an example:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   object Bar { override def toString = "Bar" }
     |   implicit def b : Bar.type = Bar 
     |}
defined module Foo
scala> implicitly[Foo.Bar.type]
res1: Foo.Bar.type = Bar
```

But while I make object Bar implicit in REPL:

```
scala> object Foo {
     |   implicit object Bar {
     |     override def toString = "isBar" }
     | }
defined module Foo
scala> implicitly[Foo.Bar.type]
res0: Foo.Bar.type = isBar
```

It seems that it doesn't need to define an implicit in the outer scope. Or do I take Joshua's meaning completely wrong?

Comment: When was the book written, and what version of Scala are you using? This might have changed a bit in 2.9 or 2.10.

Comment: Things are as in my answer at least from 2.9.x on. Josh must have been referring to Scala pre-2.9, or just been unaware of the semantics. FTR I was both surprised and delighted when I discovered that this was possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's suggested in this book that it covers 2.7.x to 2.9.x. I have 2.10 installed on my machine which might  behave differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this scenario objects act as if they were their own companions, so you simply need to nest your object-type-mentioning implicits in the body of the object itself,

```
scala> object Bar {
     |   override def toString = "Bar"
     |   implicit def b : Bar.type = Bar
     | }
defined module Bar

scala> implicitly[Bar.type]
res0: Bar.type = Bar
```

Note that here the body of `Bar` has been considered as part of the implicit scope for resolving `Bar.type`.

This might appear to be an obscure corner of Scala's type system, but I was able to put it to good use in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s encoding of [polymorphic (function) values](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/commit/447aae489dd1b7b47fc2d7cc027ca73844a76550).

Answer (score 2):

If you put the following code in a file and try to compile using `scalac` it fails with a `'implicit' modifier cannot be used for top-level objects`

```
 implicit object Foo {
  object Bar { override def toString = "Bar" }
 }
```

This however compiles fine:

```
 object Foo {
  implicit  object Bar { override def toString = "Bar" }
 }
```

I believe using the `REPL` `implicit's` are not exactly top-level hence the seeming inconsistency.